# Delete records in db2 from SQL Server via odbc

Tags: sql-server, db2, odbc, openquery

I have an ODBC connection to a db2 system from SQL Server. I can use `OPENQUERY` to select, insert, and delete records from my intended table.

But, I need to routinely delete all records from a table and when trying to delete the entire contents I'm getting errors about isolation levels, but I think it actually has to do with the the number of rows I'm attempting to delete at one time.

I can loop thru and delete about 600 at a time, but that's a hack for now.

Any suggestions on how to more effectively do this?

Error I'm getting:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MY_SERVER" returned message "Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is supported.".
>
> Msg 7392, Level 16, State 2, Line 32
>   Cannot start a transaction for OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MY_SERVER".

Comment: you can use OpenRowSet to do it alternatively. But make sure you have a right permission to perform a delete action.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to delete ALL records in the DB2 table why don't you try:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE <mytable>
```

I think you can run it via EXEC in OLE DB (this is not ODBC) using something like this:

```
EXEC <mylinkedserver.db>sp_executesql 'TRUNCATE TABLE <mytable>'
```

Comment: I tried that but I don't have the privs for it.  Also, at least in sql server, truncate won't work if there are any tables with a FK to the table.  That's not the case here, but it's a common reason why truncate isn't always an available solution.